# Inserting Dates Into Mongo with Golang

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

I am trying to create a Golang MongoDB connector that takes in a request from a client and updates/inserts the request body into a database. An example of the request body is:

```
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": <hexOID>
        },
        "DateCreated": {
            "$date": 1460091636474
        },
        "DateModified": {
            "$date": 1542241349721
        }
    }
```

The current Mongo driver and BSON library I am using is the one located at github.com/globalsign/mgo/ and github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson respectively.

Whenever I try to unmarshal the above response, I get an error:

```
cannot parse date: "{\r\n        \"$date\": 1460091636474\r\n    }"
```

I've read around and saw some answers about creating a custom marshaller/unmarshaller but how would I go about doing that if it does solve this problem?

A subset of my code is as follows:

```
var update interface{}
errUpdate := bson.UnmarshalJSON(body, &update)
if errUpdate != nil {
    fmt.Println(errUpdate)
}
dbErr = collection.Update(query, update)
```

I keep update as an interface since the request body that is passed constantly changes and is not well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the format of JSON in your example is called [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/). This is important, as you need to follow the format for [extended JSON date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#data_date). It's either `$date` with ISO-8601 string, or `$date` with `$numberLong` with Unix Epoch.

Another note is with `Update` you need an update operation i.e. [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/). If you're intending to replace the document, use `Replace`. Although replacing `_id` doesn't quite make sense, the example below will use `Replace` as assumed from the example.

Given an example document in database as below:

```
db.collection.insert({
              "_id": ObjectId("5bf36072a5820f6e28a4736c"),
              "Foo":1
})
```

An alternative to using `globalsign/mgo` is to use [mongo-go-driver/bson](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson) package, there's a method [UnmarshalExtJSON()](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson#UnmarshalExtJSON) that you could easily utilise to parse extended JSON.

Using the current version (0.0.18), an example would be:

```
import (
    "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson"
    "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo"
)

replacement := bson.D{}
// Example of response body
data := `{"_id":{"$oid":"5bf36072a5820f6e28a4736c"},"DateModified":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1542241349721"}},"DateCreated":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1460091636474"}}}`

err = bson.UnmarshalExtJSON([]byte(data), true, &replacement)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
query := bson.D{{"Foo", 1}}
replaceResult, err := c.ReplaceOne(context.Background(), query, replacement)
```